# Show that if $x \in R$ is homogeneous element of nonzero degree, then $1-x$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

> Let $R$ be a $\mathbb Z$-graded ring and let $M$ be graded $R$-module. Show that $x \in R$ is homogeneous element of nonzero degree then $1-x$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$.

I showed that if an element $m \in M$ is homogeneous and $(1-x)m=0$, then $m=0$.

Let $m=m_a +\cdots + m_{a+n} \in M$ where $n \ge 1$ and $\deg m_{a+i} = a+i$.

If the degree of $x$ is strictly greater than $n$, then we have all $m_a, \dots, m_{a+n} =0$.

However, when $0 < \deg x \le n$, I am stuck.

**How can we show that $m=0$?**

Comment: "I showed that if an element $m\in M$ is homogeneous, then $m=0$", huh?  That would mean $M=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 We want to show that $1-x$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$. So we want to show that if $(1-x)m=0$, then $m=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 the asker's explanation of what they are doing is just very poor. To show that $1-x \in R$ is not a zero divisor, they want to show that if $(1-x)m = 0$ then $m=0$. I have no idea what their attempted argument is because all they need to do is expand it to $m - mx$ and observe $mx$ has strictly greater degree than $m$ and so they can't cancel.

Comment: @TokenToucan Are you assuming $m$ is homogeneous? If not, then your argument is not sufficient.

Comment: @TokenToucan If you are assuming $m$ is homogeneous, then that was exactly my argument. Now we must take an element in $M$ that is not homogeneous.

Comment: @AlJebr you should be able to take it from there. Just take the top degree term of $m$ and then...?

Comment: @TokenToucan I don't think it is that easy. Let $\deg x = i$ with $0 < i \le n$. Then each $m_a, \dots, m_{a+i-1}=0$. But that's all we have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is some $m$ such that $(1-x)m = 0$. Denote by $m_i$ the $i$th homogeneous component of $m$. Let the "bottom degree" of $m$ be the smallest $k$ such that $m_k \neq 0$.

First assume that the degree of $x$ is positive. Then just consider the bottom degree term of $(1-x)m$: it must be $m_k$ since $x$ is homogeneous of degree $>0$. Thus $(1-x)m =0$ would require $m_k = 0$, contradicting our assumption that it is nonzero.

In the case that the degree of $x$ is negative, consider instead the top degree term.

Comment: What do you mean by "let $n$ be the degree of $m$" ? I thought only homogeneous elements have a defined degree.

Comment: Just like $z^3+z+1$ has degree 3.

Comment: Ok. Got it now.

Comment: I’ll edit that out anyways since it looks like never ended up using the degree (I think I did in the first version but then simplified it)

Comment: Looks good. Your proof is actually just a direct proof by contrapositive since what you show is: If $m_k \ne 0$, then $(1-x)m \ne 0$.